# In IntellIJ IDEA how can I exclude a few files from find in path?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I do a find all (Ctrl-Shift-F) it takes very long, because I have some autogenerated js files in my project that are quite large.

How can I exclude those files from my searches?

Obviously I don't want to exclude all js files.

IntelliJ let's you pick one or more file types to search, but is there any way to search everything *except* 2 or 3 known files.

I tried marking them as ignored, but they still show up in searches.

The help is here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.3/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#limit_search

It recommends restricting to a directory, or a module, but there are quite a few directories and it's all in the same module, so that does not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the File Mask you can use ! oparand to exclude the files for example for not in js file then the file mask would be !*.js. You can use , to add multiple conditions to exclude or select the file types you are interested into.

Comment: Nice! doing !my-file.js and it is excluded. They should document that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
!*.json, !*.txt,!*.js,!*Test*.java,*.java
```

[image]

In IntelliJ 2021, you can include specific file type by *.ext1 separated with commas and to exclude !*.ext2

Refer image, I need only *.java file and not !*.js
you can also exclude !*Test*.java as well.